# Why are some nouns declined like adjectives?

Tags: grammar-identification, declension, nominalization

It was noted in a previous question that *der Beamte* is declined like an adjective altho it's a noun. Is there a deeper reason to this? Do the nouns which are declined like adjectives share something in common? Thanks.

Comment: I noted this reason in the answer you noted. Did you not read it?

Comment: I had asked this before the edit. It's pretty urgent to me that I get this cleared because I have an exam of topics which I am asking of in about 13 days @OranMatheus

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. Adjectivic declension of nominalized adjectives

All nouns that derive from adjectives are declined in a very special way, because, although they are nouns (they have articles and are written with an uppercase first letter), the adjective still is alive inside this word and influences the grammatical behavior:

- **adjective used as attribute of a noun**
  The indefinite article that is used here to indicate the gender of the noun belongs to the noun, not to the adjective.

  > masculine: ein schöner Löffel, ein schöner Mann
  > feminine: eine schöne Gabel, eine schöne Frau
  > neuter: ein schönes Messer, ein schönes Kind
- **nominalized adjective**
  The article still indicates the gender of the noun, but now the noun is a word that is derived from an adjective and so keeps many of the properties of the adjective

  > masculine: ein Schöner
  > feminine: eine Schöne
  > neuter: ein Schönes

#### 2. Origin of the noun »Beamter«

###### Noun: [das Amt](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Amt)

The German noun *»das Amt«* means *agent, department, office,* so, an *Amt* is a sub-unit of the government. An *Amt* is never a private organization or part of it. *Amt* describes the logical unit or department. Sometimes *Amt* even means the whole government.

> Das **Amt** der Steiermärkischen Landesregierung ist in rund 20 Dienststellen aufgeteilt, die an unterschiedlichen Standorten in der Stadt Graz untergebracht sind.
> The Office of the State Government of Styria is divided into about 20 offices, which are located at different sites in the city of Graz.

The word *Amt* also describes the physical location of the authority, i.e. the whole building or that part of a building that is used by the authorities.

> Im Standes**amt** Wien-Zentrum gibt es zwei Trauungssäle.
> There are two wedding halls at the Vienna City Center Registry Office.

A third meaning of *Amt* is the power that is given from the authorities or from the people to a single person when this person works as employee of an official agency or department.

> Es sind meistens Männer, die das **Amt** eines Bürgermeisters inne haben.
> It is mostly men who hold the office of mayor.

###### Verb: jemanden beamten; Participle: jemand wird/ist beamtet

This verb is rarely used, and when its used, then it almost always is used in sentences using passive voice, so when it appears in a German sentence, it does so in form of a participle:

- Zustandspassiv (state passive)

  > Herr Müller ist schon seit 30 Jahren beamtet.
  > Mr. Müller has been appointed as a civil servant for 30 years.
- Vorgangspassiv (process passive)

  > Markus wird bald beamtet werden.
  > Markus will soon be appointed as a civil servant.

###### Adjective: [beamtet](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/beamtet)

Participles are twilight beings, located in the intermediate world between verbs and adjectives. They are usually derived from verbs but can be used like adjectives, and many of them are used so rarely as verbs and so often as adjectives that they are counted entirely among adjectives. The word *beamtet* is such a word, and this is also the reason why neither the verb *beamten* nor the participle *beamtet* are listed in dictionaries. You only can find the adjective *beamtet.*

> Wie viele **beamtete** Universitätslehrerlnnen gibt es? ([source](https://www.parlament.gv.at/dokument/XXIII/J/4622/imfname_112836.pdf))
> How many tenured university teachers are there?

###### Nominalized adjective: [ein Beamteter](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Beamteter), [eine Beamtete](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Beamtete)

This is a normal nominalized adjective, as described in section 1 of my answer. Grammatically, it behaves like any other nominalized adjective. It is only used very rarely because there has been a shortened form of this nominalized adjective since the 14<sup>th</sup> century:

###### Shortened nominalized adjective: [ein Beamter](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Beamter), [eine Beamte](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Beamte)

This word is not a "real" noun, but still a nominalized adjective and therefore declined like a nominalized adjective:

- without article: strong declension

  > masc.: Herbert ist Beamter.
  > fem.: Sabine ist Beamte.
  > (no neuter form, because only persons can be *Beamter* and there are no neuter persons.)
- definite article: weak declension

  > masc.: Der Beamte heißt Huber.
  > fem.: Die Beamte heißt Fink.
- indefinite article: mixed declension

  > masc.: Ein Beamter arbeitet für ein Amt.
  > fem.: Eine Beamte arbeitet für ein Amt.

But note, that the feminine form shown here is used very rarely, because there is an alternative feminine form:

###### Feminine noun: [die Beamtin](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Beamtin)

This is a full noun, i.e. it's not a nominalized adjective, and therefore not declined like an adjective, but like every other noun:

> Sabine ist Beamtin.
> Die Beamtin heißt Fink.
> Eine Beamtin arbeitet für ein Amt.

Comment: "jemanden beamten" must be Austrian German. In Germany, it is "jemanden verbeamten".

Comment: I would also argue that only "beamtet" exists, not "beamten". This is one of the cases where adding a prefix and suffix happens at the same time, just like the "ver-"+"-rn" combination in "vergrößern", where "vergroß" and "größern" both don't exist. Or like "beliebt", which is not connected to "belieben", but rather "be-" and "-t" added to "lieben" at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Because they are nominalized adjectives who got another use as a common term for a thing. This happens very very often. Those nouns do not have anything else in common.

- der/die/das Neue
- der/die/das Fremde
- das Gute
- das Böse
- der/die Blinde
- der/die Kriminelle
- der/die Kranke
- der/die Obdachlose
- der/die Deutsche
- …

And it happens to participles as well (as they are like adjectives):

- der/die Reisende
- der/die Überlebende
- der/die Betrunkene
- der/die Bekannte

And even to gerundives:

- der/die Auszubildende